# Отправка сообшения на почту через localhost

Tags: php, yii

[image: Сообщения ошибки]Всем привет.Так как я новичок в YII решил задать вопрос тут.У  нас в локальном хосте запушщен большой проект типо booking.com .Мне нужно посмотреть как выгялдит сообшения которое приходит на почту чтобы отредактировать его.Когда я заполняю все поля и ввожу забронировать выводит ошибку `Connection could not be established with host smtp.yandex.ru [ #0]` У нас на проекте подключен расширения для почты `swiftmailer.`
main.php выглядет следуищем образом

```
[![<?php

/**
 * @author FilamentV <vortex.filament@gmail.com>
 * @copyright (c) 2015, Thread
 */

return \[
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'runtimePath' => '@cache/frontend',
    'layoutPath' => '@app/layouts',
            'bootstrap' => \[
            'debug'
        \],
    'modules' => require(__DIR__ . '/modules.php'),
    'components' => \[


         'mailer_booking' => \[ 
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
             'transport' => \[
                 'class' => \Swift_SmtpTransport::class,
                 'host' => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
                 'username' => 'login@domen.com',
                 'password' => 'password',
                 'port' => '465',
               'encryption' => 'ssl',
             \],
             'useFileTransport' => false,

        \],

           'mailer_info' => \[
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
             'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
                     'transport' => \[
                         'class' => \Swift_SmtpTransport::class,
                         'host' => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
                         'username' => 'login@domen.com',
                         'password' => 'password',
                         'port' => '465',
                       'encryption' => 'ssl',
                     \],
                    'useFileTransport' => false,


        \],
        'assetManager' => \[
            'bundles' => \[
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => \[
                    'sourcePath' => null,
                    'basePath' => '@webroot',
                    'baseUrl' => '@web',
                    'css' => \['css/bootstrap.css'\],
                \],
            \],
        \],
        'urlManager' => \[
            'rules' => require(__DIR__ . '/rules.php')
        \],
        'i18n' => \[
            'translations' => \[
                'front' => \[
                    'class' => \yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource::class,
                    'basePath' => '@frontend/messages',
                    'fileMap' => \[
                        'front' => 'front.php',
                    \]
                \],
            \]
        \],
    \],
    'params' => require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
\];][1]][1]
```

Comment: Если вы реальные логины и пароли показали в своем вопросе, то рекомендую сменить их сейчас же на другие на почтовом сервере.

Comment: @Visman почтовой сервер  в этом файле находится ?И на какой сменить ?или это не имеет значение ?

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно посмотреть как выгялдит сообшения которое приходит на почту

Для проверки можешь поиграться с useFileTransport. Можешь выставить true прыгнуть в /runtime/mail и там уже проверить свое письмо.

Comment: почекаю.А зачем нужно посмотреть как выгялдит сообшение ?

Comment: Попробуй эту штуку убрать 'encryption' => 'ssl' и изменить 'smtp.yandex.ru' на 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru'

Comment: Просто первоначально из вопроса я понял что тебе просто надо посмотреть какое письмо формируется, а не сама отправка. По этой причине я тебе предложил использовать usefiletransport и посмотреть содержимое.

Comment: спасибо на данный момент я не работаю над этой задачой   но через пару дней перейду и скажу вам обязательно.Большое спасибо что помогаете

Comment: сделал то что вы сказали теперь ошибка показывает                                Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.yandex.ru [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]  @Всеволод Рябчиков

Comment: При подобной конфигурации сам только что проверил с яндексом все работает, одно НО. Он чисто требовал что бы setFrom был заполнен указанным в майлере почтой. Проблема в конфигурации самого сервера. В гугле вот что нашел ""Connection could not be established with host" показывается, когда PHP функция stream_socket_client() не смогла подключиться к серверу. Почему она не смогла это сделать, пока непонятно. Судя по коду ошибки 0, хостинг запретил открывать сокеты."

Comment: Хочу отметить в какую сторону смотреть. Перед stream_socket_client убираешь собачку, и после вызова 267 строчки вар дампом глянь содержимое $this->stream. И там уже увидишь что именно ему не нравится